# jQuery - Fadein fadeout error with css animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I want to run a loading animation when a webpage is opened, which then fades out and is replaced with another `div`. I am using jQuery, but it seems like the animation is interfering with `fadein` and `fadeout` for some reason and I cannot figure it out.

The jQuery works in this case:

http://jsfiddle.net/jgTh2/12/

But the same code does not work with the css animation:

https://jsfiddle.net/xkuyL7uy/

The animation is from here:

http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: you have to include jQuery library for your javascript code. press on javascript and choose jQuery latest version, section "Frameworks and Extensions"

Comment: Your second fiddle doesn't have jquery loaded as an external resource, so basically all of your javascript is ignored (since it's all jquery).

Comment: How stupid of me! But when I include it I receive this error `// tell the embed parent frame the height of the content if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){ window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", { height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height, slug: "None" }], "*") }`

Comment: @ggordon This error is because you are calling next on an element that is display:none, then trying to use it again. See my answer below for a fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that you have it set up needs a height (once you include jQuery) and the fadeout makes the element go to display:none which has no height. The issue happens because you call the next() function on a display:none element and then try to use it. Just use a timeout instead of the .next().delay(1000)

https://jsfiddle.net/xkuyL7uy/4/

```
$('#id').hide();

var spin = $(".spinner");

spin.fadeOut();

setTimeout(function() 
{
    spin.fadeIn();
}, 2000);
```

If you would like to control the length of the fade use this

https://jsfiddle.net/xkuyL7uy/3/

```
var spin = $(".spinner");

fadeTo(spin, 0);

setTimeout(function() 
{
    fadeTo(spin, 1);
}, 1000);

function fadeTo(selector, num) {
   selector.fadeTo(1000, num);
}
```

To keep the fade going, use an interval like this

https://jsfiddle.net/xkuyL7uy/5/

```
$('#id').hide();

var spin = $(".spinner");

fadeTo(spin, 0);

setInterval(function() {
    fadeTo(spin, 1);
    setTimeout(function() 
    {
        fadeTo(spin, 0);
    }, 1000);
}, 1000);

function fadeTo(selector, num) {
   selector.fadeTo(1000, num);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(1)- i don't know what is this line :

`$('#id').hide();`

(2)-
if you copied the code from this https://jsfiddle.net/xkuyL7uy/ to this http://jsfiddle.net/jgTh2/12/ it will work, i guess you did not link to jquery or something.

(3)- try this method to do what you want it is working:

```
$(".spinner").fadeOut(); 
setTimeout(function() {
                   $(".spinner").fadeIn();
                }, 1000);
```

i hope this was useful . the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jgTh2/14/

Answer (score 0):

I see you haven't included the jQuery link in the bottom of your body tag (fixed: [click me](https://jsfiddle.net/yph8dsqw/)).

```
    HTML:
    <div id="box"><h1>HELLO</h1></div>

    <div class="spinner">
      <div class="dot1"></div>
      <div class="dot2"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- This is what I meant -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>


    CSS:
    .spinner {
      margin: 100px auto;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;

      -webkit-animation: sk-rotate 2.0s infinite linear;
      animation: sk-rotate 2.0s infinite linear;
    }

    .dot1, .dot2 {
      width: 60%;
      height: 60%;
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      background-color: #333;
      border-radius: 100%;

      -webkit-animation: sk-bounce 2.0s infinite ease-in-out;
      animation: sk-bounce 2.0s infinite ease-in-out;
    }

    .dot2 {
      top: auto;
      bottom: 0;
      -webkit-animation-delay: -1.0s;
      animation-delay: -1.0s;
    }

    jQuery:
    $('#id').hide();
    $(".spinner").fadeOut().next().delay(1000).fadeIn();
```

If you are not sure you can check out this:
[click me](https://jsfiddle.net/esvsa3a6/). However, what you were trying to do was directly fade out the animation but what if the page wasn't loaded. I recommend animating when the page is loaded (see my example).
 Best regards,
 Sinestro White